# Altium - How to disable white (polygon?) outlines during interactive routing

Tags: altium

I seemed to have pressed some hotkey activating a white outline around same layer objects during interactive routing. See image below. It seems to slow down FPS quite a bit, so I'd like to disable it. Can someone tell me (1) What the white outline means / what it's for (2) How to disable it?

[image]

Comment: At a guess, that's probably showing the clearances.

Comment: You can "shelve" your polygons, so it won't have to calculate how to rearrange them as you route the track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Hearth is correct.

Try Preferences->Interactive Routing->Interactive Routing Options and de-select "Display Clearance Boundaries".

Comment: yes, thank you! I enabled it by pressing ctrl+w instead of shift+w to select user track width.

Comment: Excellent. When I was learning I used the View->Desktop Layouts->Default a lot.